# horizon zero dawn - artifact sets

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

Is there any downside to selling an artifact set before collecting them the other sets?
I've gotten a set of coffee mugs, but am hesitant to sell if it could void a trophy later on.

Answer (score 2):

No, there's no downside. You will get the same rewards no matter when you sell them, or how many you sell at once. None of the trophies relate to selling the artifact sets at all, only to collecting them.

Comment: Side note, when you sell the artifact, it does not remove the artifact from the collectibles menu. This is what needs to be complete to get a trophy for the artifact collection, not your inventory of them.